# JSON file simultaneous reads

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've been tinkering a bit on a small application which would show a limited amount of data to the viewer in a nicer way. I was thinking instead of opting for a database (be it SQLiteor / MongoDB) to have my data stored in a simple json file. It would have below characteristics:

- Static data (will never have to be updated - 100-150 arrays)
- Not private data - can be freely accessed by anybody which has access to the application
- Offline application (not a single connection with internet)
- Multiple users which would **read** only the data
- JavaScript being used for this

What I am wondering about though is simultaneous reads. The application would never be used to update the data, it remains static. However there might be several people using the application simultaneously. As the tool will be stored on a shared drive, accessible by several other clients at the same time (only to read the file).

As I haven't touched anything with data or databases yet, I'd wanted to see if anybody already tried this out before I go into it deeper.

I am aware of the implications in terms of security however the data inside the application is not secure data and can be accessed by anybody freely. I only want to show it in a nice way. And as it is static anyway I was going to opt for a JSON file i/o starting to work with a database to speed up the development.

Comment: This is too broad, and too un-specific at the same time. No mention of languages or protocols intended/needed to be used, no actual usable quantification of what "a limited amount of data" actually means, etc. pp. - I'd say, go for it, built it - and even if you might have to re-build it at some point, you can consider it a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your description, I think that there should be no conflict.  You should be fine.

It's actually fairly common to use JSON-formatted files to store truly-static data.